# Why isn't my react app mapping my graphQL query?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, graphql, apollo, semantic-ui

I am working on a component to map all posts from a graphQL query on the client side using semantic UI. I am running it locally and the webpage is not showing any of the data even though this query works in apollo studio.

Here's the code for the component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/client';
import { GET_POSTS } from '../utils/queries';

export const PostFeed = () => {
    const { loading, data } = useQuery(GET_POSTS, {
        fetchPolicy: "no-cache"
    });
    const posts = data?.post || [];

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Post feed</h1>
            {loading ? (
                <div>Loading...</div>
            ) : (
                <div className="ui feed">
                {posts.map((post) => {
                    return (
                    <div className="event post">
                        <div className="label">
                            {/* <img src={post.author.profilePic}/> */}
                        </div>
                        <div className="content">
                            <div className="summary">
                                <a className="user">
                                    {post.postAuthor}
                                </a>posted on their page
                                <div className="date">
                                    {/* {post.createdAt} */}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="extra text">
                                {post.postText}
                            </div>
                            <div className="meta">
                                <a className="like">
                                    {/* <i className="like icon"></i>{post.likes} */}
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    );
                })}
             </div>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Here is the utils/queries code:

```
import { gql } from '@apollo/client';

export const GET_POSTS = gql`
query GetPosts {
  getPosts {
    _id
    postAuthor
    postText
  }
}
`;
```

I wrote the below code to ensure the query is pulling data and it does return the correct data points (shared in screenshot).

```
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_POSTS);

  if (loading) return "Loading...";
  
  if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;
  
  return (<div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>);
```

[stringify data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODBmD.png)

So the problem seems to be with the mapping function or semantic UI. The page does briefly showing the Loading div before disappearing.[semantic ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Lx81.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're referring to `data.post` when you should be referring to `data.getPosts`.

Try:

```
const posts = data?.getPosts || [];
```

Comment: actually "getPosts" worked rather than "GetPosts". Either way - thank you!!

Comment: sorry, miscapitalized it the first time. Glad it works.